# Router Alert options on IGMPv2 packets

Tags: c, ip, igmp

I'm trying to forge an IGMPv2 Membership Request packet and send it on a RAW socket.

The RFC 3376 states:

> IGMP messages are encapsulated in IPv4 datagrams, with an IP protocol number of 2. Every IGMP message described in this document is sent with an IP Time-to-Live of 1, IP Precedence of Internetwork Control (e.g., Type of Service 0xc0), and carries an IP Router Alert option [RFC-2113] in its IP header

So the IP_ROUTER_ALERT flag must be set.

I'm trying to forge the strict necessary of the packet (e.g. only the IGMP header & payload), so i'm using the setsockopt to edit the IP options.

some useful variables:

```
#define C_IP_MULTICAST_TTL 1
#define C_IP_ROUTER_ALERT 1

int sockfd = 0;
int ecsockopt = 0;
int bytes_num = 0;

int ip_multicast_ttl = C_IP_MULTICAST_TTL;
int ip_router_alert = C_IP_ROUTER_ALERT;
```

Here's how I open the RAW socket:

```
sock_domain = AF_INET;
sock_type = SOCK_RAW;
sock_proto = IPPROTO_IGMP;

if ((ecsockopt = socket(sock_domain,sock_type,sock_proto)) < 0) {
  printf("Error %d: Can't open socket.\n", errno);
  return 1;
} else {
  printf("** Socket opened.\n");
}
sockfd = ecsockopt;
```

Then I set the TTL and Router Alert option:

```
// Set the sent packets TTL
if((ecsockopt = setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &ip_multicast_ttl, sizeof(ip_multicast_ttl))) < 0) {
  printf("Error %d: Can't set TTL.\n", ecsockopt);
  return 1;
} else {
  printf("** TTL set.\n");
}

// Set the Router Alert
if((ecsockopt = setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ROUTER_ALERT, &ip_router_alert, sizeof(ip_router_alert))) < 0) {
  printf("Error %d: Can't set Router Alert.\n", ecsockopt);
  return 1;
} else {
  printf("** Router Alert set.\n");
}
```

The setsockopt of IP_ROUTER_ALERT returns 0. After forging the packet, i send it with sendto in this way:

```
// Send the packet
if((bytes_num = sendto(sockfd, packet, packet_size, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &mgroup1_addr, sizeof(mgroup1_addr))) < 0) {
  printf("Error %d: Can't send Membership report message.\n", bytes_num);
  return 1;
} else {
  printf("** Membership report message sent. (bytes=%d)\n",bytes_num);
}
```

The packet is sent, but the IP_ROUTER_ALERT option (checked with wireshark) is missing.
Am i doing something wrong? is there some other methods to set the IP_ROUTER_ALERT option?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i've found out that the `IP_ROUTER_ALERT` has to be set by the Linux Kernel. IGMP membership requests are sent after a `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` is done and the Kernel takes charge of setting the `IP_ROUTER_ALERT` flag.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why your code is not working (it looks fine to me), but I can suggest a workaround: Drop one more layer down on your raw socket and build Ethernet frames. You may also want to take a look at [Libnet](http://libnet.sourceforge.net/), which handles building packets like this for you.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) states:

> Pass all to-be forwarded packets with
>   the IP Router Alert option set to this
>   socket. Only valid for raw sockets.
>   This is useful, for instance, for user
>   space RSVP daemons. The tapped packets
>   are not forwarded by the kernel, it is
>   the users responsibility to send them
>   out again. Socket binding is ignored,
>   such packets are only filtered by
>   protocol. Expects an integer flag.

This sounds as if the option only matters when *receiving* packets on the socket, not when sending them. If you're sending raw packets, can't you just [set the required option](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ip/option020.htm) in the IP header yourself?

Comment: The IP header is built from the underlying OS using the setsockopt calls, for instance the IP_MULTICAST_TTL is correctly set, but the IP_ROUTER_ALERT is not.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference I would recommend one of the many IGMP aware programs out there.
One example is `igmpproxy`:
https://github.com/ViToni/igmpproxy/blob/logging/src/igmp.c#L54

```
/*
 * Open and initialize the igmp socket, and fill in the non-changing
 * IP header fields in the output packet buffer.
 */
void initIgmp(void) {
    struct ip *ip;

    recv_buf = malloc(RECV_BUF_SIZE);
    send_buf = malloc(RECV_BUF_SIZE);

    k_hdr_include(true);    /* include IP header when sending */
    k_set_rcvbuf(256*1024,48*1024); /* lots of input buffering        */
    k_set_ttl(1);       /* restrict multicasts to one hop */
    k_set_loop(false);      /* disable multicast loopback     */

    ip         = (struct ip *)send_buf;
    memset(ip, 0, sizeof(struct ip));
    /*
     * Fields zeroed that aren't filled in later:
     * - IP ID (let the kernel fill it in)
     * - Offset (we don't send fragments)
     * - Checksum (let the kernel fill it in)
     */
    ip->ip_v   = IPVERSION;
    ip->ip_hl  = (sizeof(struct ip) + 4) >> 2; /* +4 for Router Alert option */
    ip->ip_tos = 0xc0;      /* Internet Control */
    ip->ip_ttl = MAXTTL;    /* applies to unicasts only */
    ip->ip_p   = IPPROTO_IGMP;

    allhosts_group   = htonl(INADDR_ALLHOSTS_GROUP);
    allrouters_group = htonl(INADDR_ALLRTRS_GROUP);
    alligmp3_group   = htonl(INADDR_ALLIGMPV3_GROUP);
}
```

and https://github.com/ViToni/igmpproxy/blob/logging/src/igmp.c#L271

```
/*
 * Construct an IGMP message in the output packet buffer.  The caller may
 * have already placed data in that buffer, of length 'datalen'.
 */
static void buildIgmp(uint32_t src, uint32_t dst, int type, int code, uint32_t group, int datalen) {
    struct ip *ip;
    struct igmp *igmp;
    extern int curttl;

    ip                      = (struct ip *)send_buf;
    ip->ip_src.s_addr       = src;
    ip->ip_dst.s_addr       = dst;
    ip_set_len(ip, IP_HEADER_RAOPT_LEN + IGMP_MINLEN + datalen);

    if (IN_MULTICAST(ntohl(dst))) {
        ip->ip_ttl = curttl;
    } else {
        ip->ip_ttl = MAXTTL;
    }

    /* Add Router Alert option */
    ((unsigned char*)send_buf+MIN_IP_HEADER_LEN)[0] = IPOPT_RA;
    ((unsigned char*)send_buf+MIN_IP_HEADER_LEN)[1] = 0x04;
    ((unsigned char*)send_buf+MIN_IP_HEADER_LEN)[2] = 0x00;
    ((unsigned char*)send_buf+MIN_IP_HEADER_LEN)[3] = 0x00;

    igmp                    = (struct igmp *)(send_buf + IP_HEADER_RAOPT_LEN);
    igmp->igmp_type         = type;
    igmp->igmp_code         = code;
    igmp->igmp_group.s_addr = group;
    igmp->igmp_cksum        = 0;
    igmp->igmp_cksum        = inetChksum((unsigned short *)igmp,
                                         IP_HEADER_RAOPT_LEN + datalen);

}
```